PyCharm couldn't connect to console (QGIS)
I am trying to set up PyCharm on Windows.
I created a new env from C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.34.3/bin/python-qgis.bat
When opening the project I get this error in the Python Console
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.3\bin\python-qgis.bat" "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2024.1/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=51768 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.pydev_rpc import make_rpc_client, start_rpc_server, start_rpc_server_and_make_client
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_rpc.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.pydev_server import TSingleThreadedServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2024.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.server import TServer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_shaded_thriftpy'
Couldn't connect to console process.
Process finished with exit code 1

I installed thriftpy, but the error persists.
Any ideas how to fix this?

There is a PR (pull request) solving this (and other problems).
I installed it through the install zip feature of the Plugin Manager.
